# How to update only one attribute of a tuple given in a PHP form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created an update form in PHP that takes the attributes of a tuple. The following query updates a tuple of the table based on the input:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $sql = "UPDATE member SET MFirst='".$_POST["MFirst"]."', MLast='".$_POST["MLast"]."',Street='".$_POST["Street"]."'
            ,number='".$_POST["number"]."',postalCode='".$_POST["postalCode"]."',Mbirthdate='".$_POST["Mbirthdate"]."' 
            WHERE memberID='".$_POST["memberID"]."'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }
?>
```

However, if not all attributes are submitted the update does not happen. How should I write the query in order to change an attribute of a tuple even if not all the attributes of the form are completed.

The form is the following:

```
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="update.php">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Member Id</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" name="memberID" SIZE="30">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" name="MFirst" SIZE="30">  
    </div> 
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" name="MLast" SIZE="30">
    </div>   
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Street Name</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="text" name="Street" SIZE="30">     
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Street Number</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="number" name="number" min=0 SIZE="30">
    </div>  
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Postal Code</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="number" name="postalCode" min=0 SIZE="30"> 
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Birth Day</label>
        <INPUT TYPE="date" name="Mbirthdate" SIZE="30">
    </div>
    <button class="btn" TYPE="submit" name="submit">Submit Info </button>
    <button class="btn" TYPE="reset" name="Reset">Reset </button>
</FORM>
```

Comment: You should read about SQL Injection, but anyways what you could to is use ternary operators to use your post value if defined or a default otherwise, such as :
$_POST["memberID"] ? $_POST["memberID"] : ""

Comment: @DylanKas where inside should i put the ? , because I put it like this :
SET MFirst='".$_POST["MFirst"]?."' and it does not accept it

Comment: Look at how it work, basically just a If/Else statement : https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: @DylanKas If I use a default empty , the tuple will change it to empty , Anything not typed I want it to remain as it is on the tuple

Comment: Then just include your set as well, something like $_POST["memberID"] ? ""SET MFirst='.$_POST["memberID"]."'" : ""

Comment: @DylanKas But if it is given as empty in the form , nothing type , how would that not change the tuple in the table on the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit any columns that are either empty or not submitted by iterating over $_POST and adding them to the "SET" list accordingly. However, this is dangerous as you should never trust any inputs received from the internet. (See [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp))

The following code does what you want whilst using mysqli [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which mitigates SQL Injection risk. It also verifies that $_POST keys are valid table column names.

Explanations are in comments:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// Assume $_POST is in this format:
// $_POST = [ "MFirst" => "John", "MLast" => "Doe", "Street" => "Infinity Loop", "number" => 1, "postalCode" => 95014, "Mbirthdate" => "01-01-1990", "memberId" => "abcde-1", "submit" => 1];

// remove $_POST elements not part of SET list
    $_POST = array_filter($_POST); //remove any empty elements
    unset($_POST["submit"]);
    $member_id = $_POST["memberId"];
    unset($_POST["memberId"]);

//stop now if form is empty
    if (count($_POST) == 0) exit(); 

// array of valid columns as keys, and their types as values (s = string, i = integer)
    $member_col_types = [ "MFirst"     => "s",
                          "MLast"      => "s",
                          "Street"     => "s",
                          "number"     => "i",
                          "postalCode" => "i",
                          "Mbirthdate" => "s",
                          "memberId"   => "s"
    ];

    $key_val = [];
    $types   = "";
    $columns = array_keys($member_col_types);
    $values  = [];

    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
// ensure all inputs are valid table columns, otherwise exit
        if (in_array($k, $columns) == false) {
            exit("");
        }
// dynamically adding only valid $_POST
        $key_val[] = "$k=?"; // [ "MFirst=?","MLast=?",...]
// grabs values to be inserted into ?
        $values[] = $v; //["John","Doe","Infinity Loop",1,95014,"01-01-1990"]
// grabs the variable types for binding values above to types like string, integer
        $types .= $member_col_types[ $k ]; // "sssiis"
    }

    $list = implode(", ", $key_val);

// add binding and value for memberId (part of WHERE) not processed in loop above
    $values[] = $member_id; //["John","Doe","Infinity Loop",1,95014,"01-01-1990","abcde-1"]
    $types    .= "s"; // "sssiiss"

    $sql = "UPDATE member SET $list WHERE memberId=?"; 
    //UPDATE member SET MFirst=?, MLast=?, Street=?, number=?, postalCode=?, Mbirthdate=? WHERE memberId=?

// prepare the query (assuming mysqli connection $conn)
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) or die($conn->error);

// bind the values to their types
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values) or die($conn->error);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);

}
```